# "An exception has occurred" comes every time I try to login with federation

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml, azure-ad-b2c, adfs

I am setting up a federation login for b2c via custom policy. I have already created office365 application which works with policy set up by wizard in azure, but now I need this with custom policy.
I use msal.js with angular for frontend which redirects to my policy. Sign in/sign up work fine.
I need to authenticate user from another federations.

I have tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-adfs2016-idp. I copy pasted the policy, provided in UserJourney and still getting an error.

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>mydomain.onmicrosoft.com</Domain>
  <DisplayName>Office ADFS</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="Office-SAML2">
      <DisplayName>Microsoft Office 365</DisplayName>
      <Description>Login with your ADFS account</Description>
      <Protocol Name="SAML2"/>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="WantsEncryptedAssertions">false</Item>
        <Item Key="PartnerEntity">https://login.microsoftonline.com/mydomain/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml</Item>
        <Item Key="XmlSignatureAlgorithm">Sha256</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="SamlAssertionSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SamlCert"/>
        <Key Id="SamlMessageSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SamlCert"/>
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="userPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="family_name"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="mydomain.onmicrosoft.com" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication"/>
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop"/>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Here is what I wrote with openid:

```
    <TechnicalProfile Id="OfficeProfile">
      <DisplayName>Microsoft Office 365</DisplayName>
      <Description>Login with your account</Description>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
      <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.windows.net/your-AD-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="ProviderName">issuer from metadata</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">office365 id</Item>
        <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">office365 id</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">openid</Item>
        <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer"/>
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="AzureADOffice" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin"/>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Here is my user journey:

```
      <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
      <OrchestrationSteps>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="MicrosoftExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="MicrosoftExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="OfficeProfile" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->

        <!-- For social IDP authentication, attempt to find the user account in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Show self-asserted page only if the directory does not have the user account already (i.e. we do not have an objectId). 
          This can only happen when authentication happened using a social IDP. If local account was created or authentication done
          using ESTS in step 2, then an user account must exist in the directory by this time. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Social" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Social" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>


        <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent 
          in the token. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- The previous step (SelfAsserted-Social) could have been skipped if there were no attributes to collect 
             from the user. So, in that case, create the user in the directory if one does not already exist 
             (verified using objectId which would be set from the last step if account was created in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />

      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
```

I want to get federation login working with my custom policy the same as it was with generated policy before.

Comment: Did you check application insights?

Comment: Can you make it little clear on the scenario you want to try? Are you trying to integrate O365 with B2C (Login with Office365 credentials into your application using B2C custom policy)?

Comment: I need to make possible to login with another federation. I have an already created office 365 app in Enterprise applications, which worked before, but I need it with custom policy.

Comment: **I need to make possible to login with another federation** what is  your another federation here? You trying out with again O365 in custom policies?

Comment: Another federation are another active directories. I want users to login to my application via existing account in some another aad. I just want to make it work as it worked before without custom policy.

Comment: Did you check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-oidc-azure-active-directory. As I seen you got ADFS integration doc and trying that for AAD.  Refer those MSDN articles and you able to integrate AAD into custom policies and your AAD users can sign-in with their credentials.

Comment: I tried both ways, nothing worked. I was going through those articles.

Comment: Can you try attaching your policies here by removing sensitive details? Also cross check whether you trying Multi-Tenant scenario in Single-Tenant or not.

Comment: I already wrote up technical profiles up and extended it now by UserJourney. The thing is that sign in/sign up with credentials works fine.

Comment: I am not trying multitenant. I do not want specific organizations, but everyone to be able to login with his organization account.

Comment: you said like sign-in/sign up with credentials works fine, this mean that Local Account is working fine but it is not working for your AAD right?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean

Comment: I tried your Technical Profile and it is working fine for me. One wild guess is in your profile you added <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer"/> but you must add client_secret as AD directory created secret.

Comment: what do you mean in ad directory? I created that in b2c -> Identity Experience Framework -> policy keys, Isn't it right? Could you write how it is called in azure menu?

Comment: Yes. If i am not wrong while creating key in policy keys you given name as B2C_1A_contosoxxxx( if you follow documentation) if yes you must give that key as client_secret in your openid technical profile

Answer (score 1):

You are making this unnecessarily complicated by federating with Azure AD using SAML protocol. Azure AD supports SAML and OpenId.
The guidance for OpenId is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom

If you **really** want to federate using SAML protocol, then the technical profile needs some modifications.

For `PartnerEntity`, the metadata URL is specific to the enterprise application registration, like this: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=8384a3a3-379d-484b-9193-747f114399b0`.

For the `cryptographicKeys` element, the certificate needs to be uploaded against the Enterprise Application in Azure AD, and marked as Active.
The same certificate needs to be placed inside the Azure AD B2C policy Keys menu, with the private key.

Here is my working example:

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-SAML2">
          <DisplayName>AAD SAML</DisplayName>
          <Description>Login with your AAD account</Description>
          <Protocol Name="SAML2"/>
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="WantsSignedRequests">false</Item>
            <Item Key="WantsEncryptedAssertions">false</Item>
            <Item Key="PartnerEntity">https://login.microsoftonline.com/06a05be1-33df-4feb-9009-95c7a27a7a49/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=8384a3a3-379d-484b-9193-747f114399b0</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <!--<Key Id="SamlAssertionSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SAMLAADIdPTokenSigningKey"/>-->
            <Key Id="SamlMessageSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SAMLAADKey"/>
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tenantid"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="contoso.com" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication"/>
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop"/>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Thanks much for the answer, actually I began to do SAML, because I have already tried openid and thought that openid does not work with federations. I am getting the same error with openid as well.

Comment: We need more details in the error, if you send the reply url to https://jwt.ms, it should have the entire error in the URL. Or if its a federation config issue, Azure AD should be returning an error with a correlationid and timestamp.
AAD B2C supports SAML and OpenID Federation.

Comment: Confusing thing is that the error is "AADB2C: An exception has occurred." and that's it, no details.

Comment: What is the tenant? something.onmicrosoft.com, and what is the policyID?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean. PolicyId is an unique name which is specified in policy, policy is an xml file with configs. Tenant is the name of b2c.